# Получение данных с dmoz

Tags: php

Нужно написать PHP скрипт, который бы определял наличие сайта в dmoz. Но скрипт должен искать наличие сайта в dmoz, если человек выполняет запрос: http://site.ru/dmoz?hashcode.ru - т.е. при таком запросе он будет искать наличие сайта hashcode в каталоге dmoz.
Как реализовать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот [здесь](http://makarou.com/parsing-dmoz) есть простой пример проверки наличия сайта в DMOZ. На базе этого не составит труда реализовать то, что Вам нужно

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите в сторону сокетов, примеров в интернетах полно, или курл, также примеров полно.
У вас выйдет простой гет запрос.